# XCode 4: How do you add an existing framework?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “add existing frameworks” in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

I know in previous version, you could right-click and go to Add > Existing Framework. I can't find a similar option in XCode 4.

Answer (score 21):

In the Project Navigator

1. select your project,

   2. select the target,
   3. go to the 'build phases' tab,
   4. open the 'Link binary with Libraries' disclosure triangle
   5. Use the + to add the library you want

Here's a pic that probably summarizes the process much better!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or9gL.png

Answer (score 3):

If you have a developer account:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/53354?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Old question but now you can also do it through File->Add Files and it automatically adds it.