# How can i get the name of image picked through photo library in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am picking an image from photo library in iphone application. How will i retrieve the actual image name.

in .h class

```
UIImageView * imageView;

UIButton * choosePhotoBtn;
```

in .m class

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender 
{
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn)
    {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    else 
    { 
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

How will i get the actual name of image ?

I m new in iphone. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864814/uiimagepickercontroller-get-the-name-of-the-image-selected-from-photo-library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864814/uiimagepickercontroller-get-the-name-of-the-image-selected-from-photo-library

Comment: @PRASAD1240 why are you posting links of questions that asked later of this question? Please at least check questions date.

Comment: Since the comment is older than both the questions that's okay in my opinion. As long as this question does not depend on versions.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

import AssetsLibrary in your file:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

And, in `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

put

```
// get the ref url
NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

// define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
};

// get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
```

so you'll get the image name in log.

*don't forget to add existing framework: AssetsLibrary.framework
Steps:

1. In the project navigator, select your project
2. Select your target
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
5. Click the '+' button
6. Select your framework
7. (optional) Drag and drop the added framework to the 'Frameworks' group

Source:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=34901
&
[How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.

Comment: Better than the accepted answer, but the image names are still something like `IMG_1754.JPG`, even for images downloaded by Safari. But this seems to the way it is, Image Capture shows the same names.

Comment: deprecated warning in iOS 9. Equiavlent is fetchAssestsWithLocalIdentifiers:options

Answer (score 9):

If you are building for iOS 9+ target, you will see a bunch of deprecation warnings with ALAssetsLibrary, i.e.:

> 'assetForURL(_:resultBlock:failureBlock:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from the Photos framework instead

As the warning describes, you should use PHAsset. Using swift 2.x, for example, you will need to add `import Photos` to your file first. Then, in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method use `fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs` to get the filename:

```
if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([imageURL], options: nil)
    let filename = result.firstObject?.filename ?? ""
}
```

This will set `filename` to be something like, "IMG_0007.JPG".

Comment: Any chance you could add an obj c translation?

Comment: PHAsset has no member filename on swift 3

Comment: Try this: 
`let fileName = result.firstObject?.value(forKey: "filename") as? String ?? "Unknown"`

Comment: By using this code unable to get the filename in ios 11.0. every time it returns nil. any solution?

Answer (score 6):

Simple Swift implementation:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let referenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {

        ALAssetsLibrary().assetForURL(referenceUrl, resultBlock: { asset in

            let fileName = asset.defaultRepresentation().filename()
            //do whatever with your file name

            }, failureBlock: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Remember about: `import AssetsLibrary`

Comment: XCode says ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated, use PHPhotoLibrary instead

Comment: For Swift, its now "import Photos"

Answer (score 5):

In Objective C, use the Photos framework and import Photos/Photos.h

Then, in your imagePickerController function
add the following to get the filename of the image from the photo library

```
NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[refURL] options:nil];
NSString *filename = [[result firstObject] filename];
```

Answer (score 2):

Though you may be able to retrieve the last path component and use it like a file name, it is not advisable to do so. These filenames are assigned by the system for iTunes to understand while syncing and are not meant for programmers to access as they could be replaced by some other images in future syncs.

A good round about for this is to assign the current Date as filenames, while saving to images picked from the gallery. You may save it in your documents or library directory and use a mapping PList file to map images to their filename.

Alternatively, you can also assign unique numbers as filenames and access the images using these values.

Answer (score 1):

**Objective C** implementation that works on **iOS 10**. ALAssetsLibrary seems to be deprecated so you should use PHAsset:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

    NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    PHAsset *phAsset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[imageURL] options:nil] lastObject];
    NSString *imageName = [phAsset valueForKey:@"filename"];

    UIImage *photo = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSLog(@"Picked image: %@ width: %f x height: %f",imageName, photo.size.width, photo.size.height);

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: how to import PHAsset?

Answer (score 0):

As of **Swift 3 and iOS8+** the .filename is not accessible any more. It is still available through self.valueForKey("filename"), but not quite legal though.

However, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523211/2650588) in the question ["iOS8 Photos Framework: How to get the name(or filename) of a PHAsset?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854937/ios8-photos-framework-how-to-get-the-nameor-filename-of-a-phasset) to be short, simple, and legal.

Answer (score 0):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
    let image             = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
    let data              = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    do
    {
        try data?.write(to: localPath!, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
    }
    catch
    {
        // Catch exception here and act accordingly
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Comment: Please add some lines explaining how your code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var fileName: String = "Attachment"

 if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {

    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil)
    let assetResource = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: assets.firstObject!)
    fileName = assetResource.first?.originalFilename ?? "Attachment"
 }
 print(fileName)
```