# How to get image file path from UIImageview

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a `UIImageView` that diaplays an image. Then I have a button titled 'save' . What I want to do is that when I click the button, it should save the image file name into a `plist` for further retrieval and stuff.

I know how to save into `plist` and all. The problem is only that I don't know how to get the file path of the image being displayed in the `UIImageView`.

I did homework and found few articles but im still confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are showing your images from local or from server?

Comment: is it stored in your local or you are downloading this image from any server...?

Comment: your answer is here !! `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314405/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-image-picked-through-photo-library-in-iphone`

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible to get the image path from a UIImage, if by path you mean the original location on disk, then i dont think that you can do it

Comment: are you getting image from photo album or other source ?

Comment: Yes I am getting image from my album in Iphone Simulator.

Comment: can you put that code here where you are adding image on imageview ??

Comment: [code]
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
 UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 
 if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) // select from album
 {
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
 } else {
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 }
 
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

Answer (score 0):

Create  `UIImageview` as `CustomImageview` class with `NSString` variable.Then while showing that image,store the image file path in that string variable.Then you can get it where ever you want with the use of that string.Use the following code

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
 @interface Imager : UIImageView  
 { 
 NSString* imageFileName; @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* imageFileName;
 }
 @end

 #import "Imager.h" 
 @implementation 
 @synthesize imageFileName
```

and the assign the filepathname where you are assigning the image like your 
`Imageview.image = UIImage;`
your  `Imageview.imageFileName=yourImageFilepath;`

to get the yourImageFilepath add "AssetsLibrary.framework" to your framework folder.Then add #import "AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h"; to the header file of your class.

then add the following code in "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo" method

```
UIImage *viewImage = yourImage;
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:   (ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
{  
if (error) 
{  
    NSLog(@"error");  
} 
else 
{  
    NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);  
}  
}];  
[library release];
```

It will return a url.that is your yourImageFilepath.

Comment: Madhumitha 

I did the same. But its not working.

this is what I have done.


`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Imager : UIImageView {
    
    NSString* imageFileName;
    
}`



@end



`#import "Imager.h"
@implementation Imager

-(void) setImage:(NSString*)fileName
{
    imageFileName = fileName;
    [super setImage:fileName];
}

@end`


Its giving warning at [super setImage:fileName]; that I can not pass String to setImage function

Comment: you can not use setImage because it take UIImage parameter not of NSString. To achieve Madhumitha solution you have to make property of imageFileName. Hope this will help.

Comment: I did try to assign imageview.imagefilename to a string variable Where im assigning my imageview.image , but imageFileName just doesn't show up in the recommendations :( 

Please help. and Thanks for all the help! Really appreciate IT.

Comment: Create your UIImageView as Imager *image = [[Imager alloc] init];image.imageFileName = yourimagepath;

Comment: Sorry Madhumati. my next question might be stupid but im really confused. 

Where actually are we getting this "yourimagefilepath" .. I mean, where are we getting the actual path of our image ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to Save the image in document folder with name image1, image2, etc or the exact name of the image if you know it. And you can save the image names in the plist. Using the names here you can do the further stuff easily.