# How to get albums from iphone camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios

can we get albums and its images from iphone camera roll? I want to show iphone camera roll albums names in my application

Can this be done using AlAssetLibrary is yes how?

Answer (score 2):

To open iPhone photo library use like that:

```
-(IBAction)pickphoto:(id)sender
{
    [self startMediaBrowserFromViewController: self usingDelegate: self];
}

- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate{

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,kUTTypeImage, nil];
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;

    mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
    return YES;

}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
 thumbnail = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Can i get the image name of a particular image from the album?

Comment: @Sabarish check this link may it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314405/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-image-picked-through-photo-library-in-iphone

Comment: Tried it, am getting the information as null. Nothing more than that :(

Comment: When i `NSLog` the dictionary - info am getting null. what could be the problem?