# Local address of the photo or image taken with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I use the UIImagePickerController to take photo or to select it from an album.  Here I put the selected image to the imageView :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.temporaryImageView.image = chosenImage;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

But How can i get the address of the selected photo on the device? or the name of it?  Is it possible?

Comment: What if you read `info` and its value for `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` key?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you;

```
NSMutableString *imageName = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0]];

CFUUIDRef ref = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if (ref) {
    [imageName appendString:NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID))];
}
[imageName appendString:@".png"];
```

I also recommend you to check this answer;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184616/2622013