# iOS8 Photos Framework: How to get the name(or filename) of a PHAsset?

Tags: ios, phasset

Im trying to get the image name using `PHAssets`. But I couldn't find metadata for filename or any method to get the image name. Is there a different way to get the file name?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to get the image name (for example name of last photo in Photos) like IMG_XXX.JPG, you can try this:

```
PHAsset *asset = nil;
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
if (fetchResult != nil && fetchResult.count > 0) {
    // get last photo from Photos
    asset = [fetchResult lastObject];
}

if (asset) {
    // get photo info from this asset
    PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    imageRequestOptions.synchronous = YES;
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
             requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                            options:imageRequestOptions
                      resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                                      UIImageOrientation orientation, 
                                      NSDictionary *info) 
     {
          NSLog(@"info = %@", info);
          if ([info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]) {
               // path looks like this - 
               // file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/###APPLE/IMG_####.JPG
               NSURL *path = [info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
     }                                            
    }];
}
```

Hope it helps.

In Swift the code will look like this

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler:
{
    (imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info) in
    if info!.keys.contains(NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey"))
    {
        let path = info![NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey")] as! NSURL
    }
})
```

**Swift 4**:

```
    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: nil)
    if fetchResult.count > 0 {
        if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject {
            let date = asset.creationDate ?? Date()
            print("Creation date: \(date)")
            PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: PHImageRequestOptions(),
                resultHandler: { (imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info) in
                    if let info = info {
                        if info.keys.contains(NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey")) {
                            if let path = info[NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey")] as? NSURL {
                                print(path)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is just dirty workaround. `PHImageFileURLKey` is undocumented key and also this URL does not have unique name in last path component if image is edited (with image filter for example).

Comment: Will the fluff always be file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/###APPLE/IMG_####.JPG ? Is there some way to cipher through that and just get the file name for instance test.png?

Comment: And is there any way from keeping the system from renaming images? If I transfer an image to my device, I would like it to maintain the same filename they have on my computer from which I am transporting them and then importing them into the app. Does that make since?

Comment: there is no key in this name under info update the answer pls

Comment: What about if you want to get the name like "18-09-04 14-57-30 1905"?

Comment: @wanttobeprofessional please see updated answer. You can find a date in asset.creationDate property, then format it like you want with (NS)DateFormatter.

Answer (score 42):

I know the question has already been answered, but I figured I would provide another option:

```
extension PHAsset {
    var originalFilename: String? {
        var fileName: String?

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: self)
            if let resource = resources.first {
                fileName = resource.originalFilename
            }
        }

        if fileName == nil {
            /// This is an undocumented workaround that works as of iOS 9.1
            fileName = self.value(forKey: "filename") as? String
        }

        return fileName
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `PHAssetResource` is available on iOS 9+ only.

Comment: I tried using your code with a sort descriptor using 'originalFilename' as key and it gives the 'Unsupported sort descriptor in fetch options' error.

Comment: For some reason my video file says "TPHM1745" as the name of the file when I use ImageCapture app in OSX to see the Camera Roll files, but your method throws "IMG_6564.MP4"

Answer (score 16):

One more option is:

```
[asset valueForKey:@"filename"]
```

The "legality" of this is up to you to decide.

Comment: There is no property named 'filename' for PHAsset. How can it work?

Comment: Magic. =] It's a private property, not exposed in public API. It's relatively to use because there are other, public API, properties called `filename`.

Comment: @CaseyHancock I think so. Looking at the time the answer was posted, it was _most likely_ tested on iOS 8. Make sure to test in order to be sure.

Answer (score 14):

Easiest solution for iOS 9+ in Swift 4 (based on skims answer):

```
extension PHAsset {
    var originalFilename: String? {
        return PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: self).first?.originalFilename
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Did I mention, that I like Swift for such things? ;)

Comment: This will give the original filename.. but not the new one that CameraRoll gives to the file.

Comment: Thanks! this is shortest method.

Answer (score 6):

> For Swift

```
asset?.value(forKey: "filename") as? String
```

> For objective C

```
[asset valueForKey:@"filename"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer with Swift when you have reference URL to an asset:

```
if let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceUrl], options: nil).firstObject as? PHAsset {

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { _, _, _, info in
                        
        if let fileName = (info?["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? NSURL)?.lastPathComponent {      
            //do something with file name
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT4:**
first `import Photos`

```
if let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL],
                                           options: nil).firstObject {


            PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { _, _, _, info in

                if let fileName = (info?["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? NSURL)?.lastPathComponent {
                    print("///////" + fileName + "////////")
                    //do sth with file name
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

What you really looking for is the **localIdentifier** which is a unique string that persistently identifies the object.

Use this string to find the object by using the:

`fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options:, fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:options:, or fetchCollectionListsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: method.`

More information is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHObject/localIdentifier)