# How to get the name of file for reference url using Photos framework?

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

This is how I get an `NSURL`:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let referenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
        //access the file name
    }
}
```

It was using `ALAssetsLibrary`:

```
let assetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
assetsLibrary.assetForURL(referenceUrl, resultBlock: { asset in

    let filename = asset.defaultRepresentation().filename()

}, failureBlock: nil)
```

but **since iOS 9 it is deprecated**.

Comment: have you check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854937/ios8-photos-framework-how-to-get-the-nameor-filename-of-a-phasset

Comment: yes, but it cannot be so complicated, additionally the asset is not fetched via url there.

Comment: you can still use your old way deprecated does not mean its removed or you can't use. otherwise you have to use its new methods and code

Comment: But I want to use new approach of Apple:)

Comment: thats why i give you this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer:

```
if let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceUrl], options: nil).firstObject as? PHAsset {

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { _, _, _, info in
                        
        if let fileName = (info?["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? NSURL)?.lastPathComponent { 
            //do something with file name
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs' is deprecated in iOS11