# How to get the image path stored in the iCloud?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage, phasset

I am using [TLPhotoPicker](https://github.com/tilltue/TLPhotoPicker) to allow the user to choose multiple images. I want to upload the images to Firebase and based on their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files?authuser=0), I need to retrieve the image's path.

@Eridana answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854937/ios8-photos-framework-how-to-get-the-nameor-filename-of-a-phasset), which is as follows:

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: selectedAssets[0].phAsset!, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler:
            {
                (imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info) in
                if info!.keys.contains(NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey"))
                {
                    let path = info![NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey")] as! NSURL
                    print(path)
                } else {

                }
        })
```

Works and prints the local image's path in the device (`file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0005.PNG`), but when I choose images stored in the iCloud, I get the following error printed to the console:

> 2017-11-04 18:17:44.423826+0400 tourPlacesApp[242:8831] [Generic]
>   Failed to load image data for asset 
>   C2717B20-5180-4CE8-AFEB-D661C259D227/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   sourceType=1, (2448x3264), creationDate=2017-07-02 06:46:00 +0000,
>   location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0  with format 9999

When I looked online, I found that I have to store the metadata of the images first inside local file and only then I will be able to get the image path.

How do I get the metadata from the images stored as PHAsset

**EDIT**

It says in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimageresultisincloudkey) that I need to download the image if it is in the iCloud, but I couldn't find where they explain how to download the image.

Comment: after 0.001 secs of googling, _violá_, that is about [iCloud file management](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, in your `TLPhotosPickerViewController.swift` class first search for `cloud` and then uncomment all methods and variables related to `cloud`, specially `requestCloudDownload(asset: asset, indexPath: indexPath)` method

Comment: try to explain why we have to do this

Comment: tlphotopicker does not allow to download images from icloud, because content on icloud are considered to be private for that user, requestCloudDownload(asset: asset, indexPath: indexPath) method allows us to enter into user's icloud and download images...thanks