# How to identify photo with the unique field like checksum(md5sum) in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I am creating an IOS app which can hide the photos the user been selected. I am able to do that, but the problem is, if the user selects again the already been selected photo, how do i need to check they are **SAME** ,i looked into the metadata info of the photo, but that can match to some other photo having same meta info, currently i have only idea to generate the checksum based on whole photo data with bytes, which i think may cause memory issue and also degrades performance.so any expertise help will be needful.thanks in advance.

```
__block NSMutableDictionary *imageMetadata = nil;
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

    if (result) {
        [self.assets addObject:result];
        NSDictionary *metadata = result.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
        imageMetadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:metadata];
        NSLog(@"%@",imageMetadata.description);
    }
};
```

Comment: see the answer from Joanne in this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314405/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-image-picked-through-photo-library-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could be handling image-identification at the front end.

If `self.assets` is an `array`, and even if your hiding photos while in a tableView (which would change the indexPaths), why not use `arrayIndex` in another array that houses all, lets say.. `NSNumbers of hidden self.assets indexes`.

But this is only after you exhausted all forms of Metadata identifiers? perhaps a combination of metadata-strings could yield something unique?

How are you dealing with this in the UI; a `TableView`?

Comment: Yes iam using indexes, but i wanted to give flexibility for users , like they can delete the photos,export to file  and mail all such things, so thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can make use of `ALAssetPropertyURLs`, which maps asset representations UTIs to URLs that uniquely identify the asset.

To get this, use `result.defaultRepresentation.url`

The url should be like `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000477&ext=JPG:`