# want to get the Image name picked from Library in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `Xamarin.ios` to develop my app and need solution to one problem. I want to get the name of the image picked from the iPhone library, im using `UIimagePickerController` for picking the image. can anyone come up with the solution please.

```
public void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia (object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reference URL: [" + UIImagePickerController.ReferenceUrl + "]");

    NSUrl referenceURL =  e.Info[UIImagePickerController.ReferenceUrl] as NSUrl;
    Console.WriteLine ("" + referenceURL.LastPathComponent);
}
```

form Objective-C i have tried this code to get image name, but doesn't work!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314405/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-image-picked-through-photo-library-in-iphone

Comment: @Igor, but i need the solution in xamarin

Comment: that's why it's just the comment. You can easy convert this code to c#.

Comment: assetsLibrary.AssetForUrl(referenceURL,
     (asset) => {
      if (asset != null) {
       var rep = asset.DefaultRepresentation;
       string name = rep.Filename;
       Console.WriteLine("name img {0}",name);
      } else {
       //tcs.TrySetResult(false);
      }
     }, 
     (failure) => { 
      //tcs.TrySetResult(false); 
     }
    );

Comment: i tried like this and worked out for me . thanks