# Foundation framework. No NSString.h file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, foundation

I'm getting a few errors just after I updated my working copy via SVN.

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCharacterSet.h:8:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCharacterSet.h:8:32: error: Foundation/NSString.h: No such file or directory

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCharacterSet.h:45:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCharacterSet.h:45: error: expected ')' before 'unichar'

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSPathUtilities.h:10:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSPathUtilities.h:10: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSString'
```

All that errors tell that compiler is unable to find NSString.h file in Foundation framework and I have opened the Foundation framework in Xcode/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers and noticed that there is no NSString header file there. Could anyone tell me what happened? I tried to delete the framework and add it again but it failed to. Still I don't have NSString header file.

Comment: are you trying to inherit from NSString? You should try NSObject instead..
Or you are missing the right Framework

Comment: No I'm not. I just want to import <Foundation/Foundation.h> but this tell me that NSString.h file doesn't exist, but is declared in Foundation.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try installing XCode again. Older SDK versions are no longer supported. Choose SDK 4.2 instead and compile it again. (I have copied the SDK 4.0 for backward compatibility but it is not shown in targets and project settings)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in a project started in XCode 3 and now compiled in XCode 4, where the line

```
 -#include <Foundation/NSString.h>
```

was flagged as no such file.  I fixed it by re-adding the framework - although it was already appearing in my project (from when I had added it in XCode 3) using this approach:

[How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

I noticed the list seen by using this method *did not* include the Foundation framework.