# Short and useful Objective-C snippets?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-snippets, xcode4

Since XCode 4, there is now a Code Snippets section which offers the snippets via auto-complete when typing. I'd be very interested in snippets you all have stored in there. What snippets save you the most time (and why)?

Please only post **actual snippets** (meaning no snarky "don't need no stinkin' snippets", and no "i love snippets that do <XYZ>"), and only snippets that are **short and sweet** (i.e. no more than ~20 lines at the most...). If a snippet is not obviously useful, also explain why you think it is. ;)

Comment: BTW, why can't i mark this question as community wiki?

Comment: Community wiki as a concept has changed over time - you can no longer simply mark a question as community wiki (although you can still tag answers in this way). However, a moderator can still make this change if requested to do so and if the question is deemed valid.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as CW, but please take care to manage this question. Flag for help if you need it. I'll re-visit it in a few days. If this starts collecting noise, we have no choice but to close it.

Comment: I've also made a minor edit to your question so that more protracted answers are invited.

Comment: just saw that. I put it back in :)

Comment: Great question! I haven't seen Xcode 4 yet and I'm on iOS at the moment, but I'll try to get to this one soon!

Comment: Well I suppose that people are not willing to give their secret formula while developing in `objective-c`

Comment: yeah so much for the "noise" :-/

Answer (score 10):

I don't if this counts but I always use this snippet whenever I add a `UITableView` in any of my view controllers.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            // Do something here......................
    }
    // Do something here too .........................
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return ;
}
```

its quite handy if you are not using a `UITableViewController` to show table contents.

Answer (score 9):

Dispatch block on the current queue after given number of seconds:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, <#seconds#>*1e9),
    dispatch_get_current_queue(), <#block#>);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are my two comment snippets. I use them a lot.

Header comment:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# pragma mark -
# pragma mark <#comment#>
# pragma mark -
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sub comment:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <#comment#>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6):

I’m often adding private class interfaces with class extensions:

```
@interface <#ClassName#> ()
@end
```

This is to keep the public interface completely free from internal stuff, especially now that we can have purely synthesized properties ([example gist](https://gist.github.com/766381)).

Answer (score 5):

A couple of collections are here:

https://github.com/mneorr/snippie/tree/master/backup

and here:

https://github.com/jad/xcode-code-snippets

which you can stick in this folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets
```

Answer (score 5):

While debugging this snippet is really useful. It let you know Class Name, Function Name and you can add your comments also.

```
NSLog(@"%s [Line %d] %@ ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__,<#comment#>);
```

Comment: I suggest you add the DLog macro to your PCH instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/969291/3141234

Answer (score 4):

There does not seem to be a class category between the factory snippets:

```
@interface <#ClassName#> (<#CategoryName#>)
@end
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the Blog, that I have created for the same purpose...

http://ios-funda.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

I also have the standard view lifecycle methods in my snippets (which get used daily):

I use keyboard shortcut <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> for

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];


}
```

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> for `viewDidLoad` etc.