# Errors from core data in iPad app

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm working on an app that will utilize core data.  I have included the CoreData.Framework but the app is throwing the following errors:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchedResultsController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSFetchedResultsController in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSEntityDescription in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSFetchRequest in RootViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

If I disable the following the app compiles without the errors:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller

/*- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }*/

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
  /*  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}    */


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller delegate

/*- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Any thoughts what I might need to add or what I missed?

Edit here is the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@class DetailViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

    DetailViewController *detailViewController;

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender;

@end
```

To complicate things I used this tutorial to get these results:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/62217-simplest-way-make-split-controller-tab-bar-controller.html

Comment: Have you added the coredata framework, and included the coredata header file? maybe copy in the .h file?

Comment: I did inclue the framework but maybe not the coredata header file.  I'll double check it.  Thanks

Comment: @MCannon I did this for the controller in question:  #import <CoreData/Coredata.h>  wich took care of all but this error:  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription"

Comment: could you post the header file for it, so we can see your declarations?

Comment: @MCannon I updated the original post to show the header file.  As well as the tutorial I used to create this project.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem. For those others that are having similar issues and make it to this post, McCannon's comment helped me out; I had forgotten to add the Core Data Framework to my project's Build Phases. If you don't know how to do this, follow the instructions here: [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the frameworks included, then do a `Clean All` on the build and recompile from scratch, that will usually resolve this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

I went through and re accomplished the tutorial and with some extra close attention it actually compiled... and I'm not 100% why.

Comment: Oh, the explanation is simple. The extra effort placated the software gnomes. Happens to me all the time.