# UIImagePicker Popup in Portrait mode only In iPhone?

Tags: ios

UIImagePicker opening in Portraite mode while my app is in ladscape mode.

[image]

code for UIimage picker is

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: See this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737632/open-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-mode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618546/force-landscape-orientation-in-uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

[Reference from Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1)