# Is it possible to show UIImagePickerController in iphone in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

My application is in Landscape. I am using `UIImagePickerController` to record a `video`. But whenever we call the `UIImagePickerController`, it is coming in portrait mode. I decided to rotate the layout of imagep picker`controller by using`UIImagePickerController` Subclass.

Through this, `image picker controller` layout is coming in Landscape. But it is working in `iPad` only. I tested in iPhone. But it is not working. Layout is not changing exactly in `iPad`.

Is it possible to show `UIImagePickerController` in iPhone in landscape mode?

First picture is, I tested in iPad. Second one is, I tested in iPhone.

Comment: This question was already answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618546/force-landscape-orientation-in-uiimagepickercontroller

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737632/open-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-mode

Answer (score 0):

As per [UIImagePickerController class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)  it is not possible:

> Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

But yes you can customize this controller to work as per your requirement.
I think if you change/replace `cameraOverlayView`(like click button and all)  to landscape  it'll automatically look like in landscape mode.