# use UIImagePickerController in landscape mode app in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

is it possible to use UIImagePickerController to fetch image from gallery without making whole app in portrait mode in iOS .Thanks

Comment: check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743388/is-it-possible-to-show-uiimagepickercontroller-in-iphone-in-landscape-mode

Comment: Problem solved by creating category class of NavigationController and adding function  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a custom class of UIImagePickerController. Override supportedInterfaceOrientations meted
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Because your app is only landscape, your view controller for the view in your
    // popover needs to support only landscape
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return yes;
}

//call custom view like this
   CustomImagePickerViewController *picker = [[CustomImagePickerViewController alloc] init];
        picker.supportedInterfaceOrientations= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I'm new in this development Please Tell me how to create custom class of UIImagePickerController?

Comment: I tried it using category but it works for app having only one view controller but my app contains multiple view controllers.

Comment: Add new file --> objective c class select subclass of as UIImagePickerController give name and create

Comment: it doesn't work because we can't create subclass of UIImagePickerController