# MFMailComposeViewController doesn't link for simulator

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, email, document

First off, I'm using XCode 4.0.2.

Okay, here is my issue. I can build Apple sample program for MFMailComposerViewController and run it in the simulator (I am aware it will not send email, I'm just concerned that it builds). That seems to work fine.

HOWEVER, when I try to build in my application I get the following message.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/lloyd/Projects/iOS/simpleApp/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI, 
    missing required architecture i386 in file
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MailData.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**SOLUTION**

Looking "Build Settings" (Basic and Combined) I saw that I had "Framework Search Path" set. This was odd because I never remembered setting that. Deleting it fixed the problem.

I am now able to build for both the simulator and the target. NOTE: You can NOT send email from the simulator, but you should still be able to run the code (if that makes sense).

Comment: This is solved... Heh...

Comment: You also get this error if you don't add the MessageUI.framework per: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Comment: True. But that wasn't the case, which was the maddening part about it all.

Comment: @FeloneousCat But the simulator seems to fake sending a email. A "Sent" result is returned...

Comment: Very good! this solved my issue :) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Looking "Build Settings" (Basic and Combined) I saw that I had "Framework Search Path" set. This was odd because I never remembered setting that. Deleting it fixed the problem.

I am now able to build for both the simulator and the target. NOTE: You can NOT send email from the simulator, but you should still be able to run the code (if that makes sense).

This was the solution to my problem :)

Comment: THAAAAANKK YOUUUU, i was going mad, but I think I know now why it happened, I was draging and dropping frameworks from another project to this one...

Answer (score 88):

In Xcode go to the build phases tab for your  target. Make sure you see MessageUI.framework. If it's not there click + to add a new framework.

Comment: MessageUI.framework was part of the build - see above where I have the "SOLUTION".

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but for others who come along from a web search, the issue might be  that you have multiple targets and you forgot to add the framework to all of them. That happened to me.

Answer (score 2):

Add [MessageUI.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html) although the docs said it is not a must.

Answer (score 1):

Add  MessageUI.framework to the project Linked Frameworks and Libraries