# i386 symbols not found

Tags: iphone, ios4, cfreadstream

Am getting this error, when using `CFReadStreamRef`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL", referenced from:
      -[FtpTestViewController clickMeToStart:] in FtpTestViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am getting no where, can someone please help?

Thanks !

Comment: This MIGHT help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938445/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-doesnt-link-for-simulator Look for my solution (which IS the correct answer to my problem, not that the framework was missing).

Answer (score 0):

In your target's "link binary with libraries" build phase is "CFNetwork.framework" included?