# How to declare CAKeyframeAnimation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to move an image along a pre defined path. I used the code below. but it says things like:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation undeclared
kCAAnimationPaced undeclared
```

I am new to iPhone development, please help me.

```
*pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimationanimationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

CGMutablePathRef pointPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pointPath, NULL, 492, 128);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pointPath, NULL, 480, 150);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pointPath, NULL, 489, 160);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pointPath, NULL, 489, 180);
pathAnimation.path = pointPath;
CGPathRelease(pointPath);

[imageview.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"pathAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 4):

You must have not imported the framework. Import it (See [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4) for help )and add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to your *.pch file.