# Can't compile plcrashreporter in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, plcrashreporter

I can use the prebuilt framework provided on the plcrashreporter project page when compiling for the device, but not for the simulator.  I have the same [problem described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192897/plcrashreporter-in-xcode-4-wont-compile-in-simulator).

---

I assume the prebuilt framework does not support the simulator's architecture, so I downloaded out the plcrashreporter source.  I opened the Xcode project and selected the `CrashReporter-iOS-Simulator > iPhone 4.3 Simulator` target.  When I try to build the project, I get this error:

```
libtool: unknown option character `D' in: -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30000
```

I get the same error when I try to build most of the other targets (such as for device).

---

My next step was to try adding the source files to my project.  I no longer have the aforementioned problem; however, I get this error when I try to compile:

```
fatal error: 'crash_report.pb-c.h' file not found [2]
 #import "crash_report.pb-c.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
Command clang failed with exit code 1
```

The `crash_report.pb-c.h` file which is mentioned in the error message simply does not exist; I've searched the plcrashreporter source tree and the internet.  Therefore, I have to assume that this file is supposed to be generated somehow, but I cannot figure out how.

(Commenting out the line in PLCrashReport.m on which `crash_report.pb-c.h` is included results in numerous other compilation errors.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that the file does not exist normally, nor does `crash_report.pb-c.c` exist, which will be your next error after this one.

The `crash_report.pb.h` and `crash_report.pb.c` files are generated at compile time through a build rule. You need to add a custom script to your build process to make them.

First, make sure you have protoc-c in the plcrashreporter folder of your project (`plcrashreporter-1.0/Dependencies/protobuf-2.0.3/bin/protoc-c`). They buried it deep. This is what your script will be running.

Then find your `crash_report.proto` file. This is the main input that `protoc-c` will be using to create your missing files. You can take this directory and put it manually into your script, OR you can make a rule to run the script on every `*.proto` file. I do the latter.

Then edit your build rules to include a script that runs `protoc-c` with the flag `--c_out="${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}"` and your `crash_report.proto` file as two inputs, this will output `crash_report.pb-c.h` and `crash_report.pb-c.c` into the same directory as where your crash_report.proto file is, which should already be accessible in your project.

The build rules in Xcode 4 (and above) are under your project's target's build rules tab. You add a build rule before all your other build rules. Here's what mine looks like in Xcode:

[image: Here's what mine looks like in Xcode.]

You'll probably have to fiddle with the directory