# PLCrashReporter not working

Tags: iphone, plcrashreporter

I had integrated PLCrashReporter framework with help this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192897/plcrashreporter-in-xcode-4-wont-compile-in-simulator). It running fine. But its not working. Not writing crash_log files.

I Used following code for forcefully crash my application. And I also attached my app.

```
   NSMutableArray *myArray=[NSMutableArray new];
   NSLog(@"myARray ho Crash : %@",[myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

[SampleCode](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10137094/tes.zip)

Any idea where going wrong...

Thanks in advance
Mandeep

Comment: Make sure you're testing outside of Xcode/gdb, as otherwise, the debugger will catch the mach exception before PLCrashReporter's signal handlers are invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Courtesy of @landonf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739413/plcrashreporter-not-working#comment9447130_7739413):

> Make sure you're testing outside of Xcode/gdb, as otherwise, the debugger will catch the mach exception before PLCrashReporter's signal handlers are invoked.

Answer (score 1):

i had also done this for mac i think you are gettign Log but on consol ,I had write the Log in textFile for Mac ...You need to also write it somewhere for iPhone Application