# Configure PLCrashReporter framework for device on xcode 4.3 beta

Tags: iphone, ios, plcrashreporter

I am successfully able to compile and run PLCrashReporter framework for ios simulator.with the help of this link

[PLCrashReporter in XCode 4 - won't compile in Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192897/plcrashreporter-in-xcode-4-wont-compile-in-simulator)

But when i replace libCrashReporter-iphonesimulator.a with libCrashReporter-iphoneos.a to test on device.all get stoped did not work application crash at

```
 PLCrashReporter *crashReporter = [PLCrashReporter sharedReporter];
```

line.

any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't not have to replace the static library, but use a combined library for the simulator and device using `lipo`. The Xcode project being part of PLCrashReporter does that all for you. On the other hand, you could use the prebuilt version available on the PLCrashReporter website or [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net) which includes a prebuilt library with an additional wrapper around PLCrashReporter to safely handle the reports and submit them to you into a database (included) or HockeyApp service.