# Cocos2D & OpenFeint installation > AVFoundation missing?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

Hey,
Well I went through the steps in that tutorial: http://pocketworx.com/?p=80, Now when I'm trying to build, I get 45 errors, they say stuff like that:

AVFoundation/AVCaptureSession.h: No such file or directory
AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h: No such file or directory
AVFoundation/AVCaptureInput.h: No such file or directory
AVFoundation/AVCaptureOutput.h: No such file or directory
AVFoundation/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.h: No such file or directory

I thought that maybe I don't have the AVFoundation framework, but I looked and "AVFoundation.framework" is in my Frameworks folder..

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not add the framework to your project.

Comment: can you read before answering?  "I thought that maybe I don't have the AVFoundation framework, but I looked and "AVFoundation.framework" is in my Frameworks folder.." , so if its in my project, how did i not add the framework to it?.. i removed it and added it again and it didnt solve the problem

Comment: did you do it like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4 ?

Comment: @Dony: also, does the problem appear on a simulator ?

Comment: I just tried to, but I don't find any build phases tab, or link binaries in my xcode, Sorry, I'm pretty new to iPhone development, and to mac..

Comment: Tried to build for the simulator, it wont give me those errors, but it gives me others, saying:   "_ABPersonCopyImageData", referenced from:      -[OFSelectContactsToInviteHeaderController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:] in OFSelectContactsToInviteHeaderController.o
/Users/user/Documents/objects/Classes/objectsAppDelegate.mm:131:0 /Users/user/Documents/objects/Classes/objectsAppDelegate.mm:131: warning: 'OpenFeint' may not respond to '+applicationWillResignActive'
and a few more..

Comment: @Dony: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8599 - Hope it will solve your problem.