# Adding Framework in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “add existing frameworks” in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

How do I add a Framework in Xcode 4?

[image]

Answer (score 89, accepted):

1. In the project navigator, select your project
2. Select your target
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
5. Click the '+' button
6. Select your framework
7. (optional) Drag and drop the added framework to the 'Frameworks' group

from [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Comment: @jimdrang, how i use touchXML library in iOS 5?

Comment: why can't I add it by right clicking and saying add new framework. So stupid from apple :)