# Cannot find ShinobiCharts Header File?

Tags: xcode, graph, charts, header, shinobi

I am using the ShinobiCharts Framework for an app I am making and Xcode Cannot find the headers to use it.

I have included the Framework by following these instructions:
[Adding Framework in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334966/adding-framework-in-xcode-4)

I have also tried copying the entire folder into the Frameworks Directory in my project.

Neither methods have enabled me to include these files

Here is the setup guide, I have not gotten past step one:
http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts/quickstartguide/drawing-a-simple-chart/

Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ShinobiCharts/ShinobiChart.h>
#import "SChartDatasource.h"
#import "ShinobiChartsDataSource.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
ShinobiChart * chart;
@end
```

Apparently ShinobiChartsDataSource is not a real thing despite being in the setup guide. Just to test too, I imported something similar sounding that was in the framework and that too threw an error. I think its an XCode issue. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to import anything other than `<ShinobiCharts/ShinobiChart.h>` these days. The quick start guide looks to be outdated and is currently being updated I believe.

You should just be able to do `<ShinobiCharts/ShinobiChart.h>` though. That's all you need to import to get past step one!

Disclaimer: I work for the Shinobi team.