# iOS UITableViewCell cell.imageView setting rounded corner

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

Hey all I am trying to set `cell.imageView`'s `cornerRadius`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=9;
```

Will it work or should I add a custom `UIImageView` in my cell to have rounded corners?

I also tried this

```
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth=2;
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
```

But it also doesn't seem to work. Has anybody faced a similar issue?

Comment: you need to set `masksToBounds` as well. Did you read `CALayer` documentation?

Comment: @Desdenova Sorry I forgot a basic thing, thanks :).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First [add Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335001/2106973) -> QuartzCore.framework to your project
then import header file in your `ViewController.m` file

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
```

Add following code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        // Rounded Rect for cell image
        CALayer *cellImageLayer = cell.imageView.layer;
        [cellImageLayer setCornerRadius:9];
        [cellImageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    }                                

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just missed setMasksToBounds. Made a terrible mistake.