# XCode error running react-native project 'JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, javascriptcore

I am trying to run a react-native project in Xcode (version 4.6.0).  I have done the following:

react-native init helloWorld then open the 'helloWorld.xcodeproj file in
    Xcode  Run using simulator (e.g. iphone 7) in XCode

I keep getting build failure, with this ....Desktop/helloWorld/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTJavaScriptExecutor.h:10:9: '**JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h' file not found**

I have tried to see how to add the library but cannot find out how.
Could anyone please point me in the right direction, any comments would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

most probably JavaScriptCore framework is missing, try to add it ([Adding Framework in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334966/adding-framework-in-xcode-4))

Your XCode is too low, consider updating it. And BTW - React Native doesn't support iOS 6 (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/330) so be sure that you are using iOS 7 or 8

Comment: Great advice .Yes thats it. Thanks a lot , updated XCode , why so difficult on a Mac I wonder, and using above iOS 6 .

Comment: Great answer , following your comments worked for me.