# _kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters referenced from... problem

Tags: objective-c, core-location

i have no idea how to solve my problem, i tried to make 100 modifications but it still tells me that message :

> _kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters', referenced from :
>   _kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters$non_lazy_ptr in SetupViewController.o
>   (maybe you meant: _kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters$non_lazy_ptr)

here's my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSMutableArray *options = [NSMutableArray array];
    [options addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLocalizedString(@"AccuracyBest", @"AccuracyBest"), kAccuracyKey, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:kCLLocationAccuracyBest], kAccuracyValue, nil]];
    [options addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLocalizedString(@"Accuracy10", @"Accuracy10"), kAccuracyKey, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters], kAccuracyValue, nil]];
    [options addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLocalizedString(@"Accuracy100", @"Accuracy100"), kAccuracyKey, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters], kAccuracyValue, nil]];
    [options addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLocalizedString(@"Accuracy1000", @"Accuracy1000"), kAccuracyKey, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer], kAccuracyValue, nil]];
    [options addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLocalizedString(@"Accuracy3000", @"Accuracy3000"), kAccuracyKey, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers], kAccuracyValue, nil]];
    self.accuracyOptions = options;
}
```

i have those importations in the .m :

> import "SetupViewController.h"
>   import < CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

and i receive 5 errors for the 5 kCL ... distance stuff (meters, hundredMeters, kilometer...)

Do you have any solution?

Thanks a lot

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you did not add the Core Location framework to the project. For instructions on how to do this in Xcode4, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4/3377682#3377682).