# Open different websites through pinpoints in mapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview

My idea is to have several (maybe as much as 100) pinpoints in a Google map.

I have created a button in the annotation message that appears when I click the pin. I want each pinpoint to be connected to a website. A different website for each pinpoint.

But at the moment I use this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
        openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.co.uk"]];
```

The problem is that with this code, all the pinpoints open the same website.

Is there any way I can specify a web address for each pinpoint?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NewClass.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapview;

NSString *myString;

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     //openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.arebikepark.se"]];

   NewClass *ann = (NewClass *)view.annotation;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ann.website]];
}

-(IBAction)getLocation {
    mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
    switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;

        default:
            break;
 }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 63.399785761795506;
    region.center.longitude =  12.91691780090332;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"Åre";
    ann.subtitle = @"www.arebikepark.se";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    ann.website = @"arebikepark.se";
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann];

    MKCoordinateRegion region1 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region1.center.latitude = 61.717050948488904;
    region1.center.longitude =  16.153764724731445;
    region1.span.longitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    region1.span.latitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    [mapview setRegion:region1 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann1 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann1.title = @"Järvsö";
    ann1.subtitle = @"www.jarvsobergscykelpark.se";
    ann1.coordinate = region1.center;
    ann.website = @"www.jarvsobergscykelpark.se";
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann1];

    MKCoordinateRegion region2 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region2.center.latitude = 57.84191869696362;
    region2.center.longitude =  12.02951431274414;
    region2.span.longitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    region2.span.latitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    [mapview setRegion:region2 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann2 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann2.title = @"Ale";
    ann2.subtitle = @"www.alebikepark.se";
    ann2.coordinate = region2.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann2];

    MKCoordinateRegion region3 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region3.center.latitude = 61.17768100166834;
    region3.center.longitude =  13.261871337890625;
    region3.span.longitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    region3.span.latitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    [mapview setRegion:region3 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann3 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann3.title = @"Kläppen";
    ann3.subtitle = @"www.klappen.se/sv/Sommar/Bikepark";
    ann3.coordinate = region3.center;
    ann3.website = @"www.klappen.se/sv/Sommar/Bikepark";
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann3];

    MKCoordinateRegion region4 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region4.center.latitude = 65.82881853569008;
    region4.center.longitude =  15.067813396453857;
    region4.span.longitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    region4.span.latitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    [mapview setRegion:region4 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann4 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann4.title = @"Hemavan";
    ann4.subtitle = @"www.bikepark.nu";
    ann4.coordinate = region4.center;
    ann4.website = @"www.bikepark.nu";
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann4];

    MKCoordinateRegion region5 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region5.center.latitude = 63.29058608431198;
    region5.center.longitude =  18.7042236328125;
    region5.span.longitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    region5.span.latitudeDelta = 100.0f;
    [mapview setRegion:region5 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann5 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann5.title = @"Örnsköldsvik";
    ann5.subtitle = @"www.hkbikepark.se";
    ann5.coordinate = region5.center;
    ann5.website = @"www.hkbikepark.se";
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann5];
}

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin =(MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyPin"];
    if (!MyPin) {
        MyPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyPin"];
        MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *details = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = details;
        MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    return MyPin;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your custom annotation class (the one that implements `MKAnnotation`) that stores the annotation's website.  Set this property when you add the annotation to the map:

```
ann.website = @"http://www.google.co.uk";
[mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

Then in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method, you can access this property:

```
MyAnnotationClass *ann = (MyAnnotationClass *)view.annotation;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ann.website]];
```

---

Based on the additional code you posted, the problem is that the website url strings don't have the `http://` scheme prefix which the `URLWithString` method needs to convert the string to a URL.  Because the url strings are invalid, the method returns `nil` which results in the `openURL` method doing nothing.

So, for example, the lines that set the `website` property should be:

```
ann.website = @"http://www.arebikepark.se";
ann1.website = @"http://www.jarvsobergscykelpark.se";
ann2.website = @"http://www.alebikepark.se";  //(line was missing completely)
ann3.website = @"http://www.klappen.se/sv/Sommar/Bikepark";
ann4.website = @"http://www.bikepark.nu";
ann5.website = @"http://www.hkbikepark.se";
```

Additionally, though the above urls are not a problem, if you intend to use urls with query strings that might contain special characters, you'll also need to escape the url string before passing it.  One way is to use the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5412596/467105) by Dave DeLong for an example and some precautions/limitations/alternatives with that method.

Finally, unrelated to your main issue but, here are some additional comments on the code:

- You don't need to create a region for each annotation just to set its coordinate.  You can just do `ann.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(63.399785761795506, 12.91691780090332);`
- If you are not using ARC, there are several memory leaks.
- In `viewForAnnotation`, you should add an `else` part to the `if` statement: `else MyPin.annotation = annotation;` in case an annotation view is re-used for a different annotation.  It probably won't happen with so few annotations but it's logically and technically required.
- If you want the user location to appear as a blue dot instead of a red pin, you'll need to add this to the top of the `viewForAnnotation` method: `if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) return nil;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even though I don't get any errors, nothing happens when i click the buttons. Here is my code

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even though I don't get any errors, nothing happens when i click the buttons. Here is my code

Comment: Please click the "edit" link under your question and add the code to it.

Comment: Now I have entered the code from viewController.m Thank you very much again!

Comment: Thank you so much! Now its working. I also changed the other suggestions but I'm having some trouble with the first one about CLLocationCoordinate2d. I tried to just add this line of code to my annotation and remove the region-part. But that did't work. Could you explain this a bit further? Thank you once again!

Comment: Did you get a compiler warning or error?  What did it say?  To use the CLLocationCoordinate2DMake function, you'll need to add the Core Location framework.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987685/what-could-be-the-reason-for-this-error-during-build-undefined-symbols-for-ar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530733/error-while-implementing-kmlviewer-in-my-project.

Comment: I have changed to a plist now, so I got rid of the extra code. Thank you so much for all the help!!!