# iOS AWS S3 implementation tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking to implement Amazon Web S3 service in one of my iPhone apps, but I was wondering if anyone knows where I can find a tutorial or some example code of how to implement the SDK on the iPhone. I'll really appreciate your help.

The comments of this post "[How to use the AWS SDK for IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631634/how-to-use-the-aws-sdk-for-ios)" don't show the tutorial I'm looking for.

I'm looking for an explanation of how things work between the device and S3 to know how to implement my solution.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631634/how-to-use-the-aws-sdk-for-ios

Comment: Check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631634/how-to-use-the-aws-sdk-for-ios/26314550#26314550

Answer (score 3):

I help maintain the AWS SDK for iOS.  I encourage you to just [download the SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/).  It includes a couple of samples that cover S3 as well as a number for other services.  Each sample includes an article that explains the sample.

You might also want to checkout our [Mobile Developer Blog](http://mobile.awsblog.com/) which contains some posts related to higher level features of the SDK.

If none of these resources answer your question, I'd appreciate the feedback about the kind of samples would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

See [This Amazon Page](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271) - it helped me when I was at your point.