# Add a ".a"-library to Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I already read a lot of hints how to add an existing framework to Xcode 4, e.g.: 
http://www.thinketg.com/Company/Blogs/11-03-20/Xcode_4_Tips_Adding_frameworks_to_your_project.aspx

But my question is very special.

I want to add a library that has the following structure:

- build -> Debug-iphoneos -> library.a
- build -> Debug-iphonesimulator -> library.a
- build -> Release-iphoneos -> library.a
- build -> Release-iphonesimulator -> library.a

If I want to build my project to test it on a simulator, I have to copy the library from the folder "Debug-iphonesimulator" to my project. If I want test it on the device, I have to copy the library from the folder "Release-iphoneos". That's very cumbersome!

Is the a good way to integrate all librarys in my project?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first step is to create universal static library with the lipo command

```
lipo -create "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${BUILD_STYLE}-iphoneos/libYourLib.a" "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${BUILD_STYLE}-iphonesimulator/libYourLib.a" -output "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/libYourLib-${BUILD_STYLE}.a"
```

After that create 2 different target (for debug and release) and add the correct .a in each.

Comment: Creating a universal static library with lipo has worked and I copy my target to get another one, but how do I add the .a in the target?

Comment: Select tour target > build phase > link binary with library > (+) and choose your .a file. The .a file must be added in the Xcode project

Comment: You really have to create two different targets, one for debug and one for release?  That kinda sucks.

Comment: You only have to do that if you have to use library build for Debug & Release. Why don't you just use Release for device and Debug for simulator?

Answer (score 0):

There is another simple way. Provide the path of .a file in other linker flag with the corresponding target.

Suppose you are building your application for device it should link to device version of .a and when you are building your application for simulator it should link to simulator version on .a

Here is how you should provide the other liker flag:

```
../../../testApp/DerivedData/testApp/build/Products/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/testApp.a
```