# iOS - _OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo not found?

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I am using the following code to get network info about my iPhone -

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>


CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

But I get the error -

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Isn't the class a part of the iOS SDK? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It is part of the [CoreTelephony.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603). You need to [add that framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4) for your code to work.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. Mine was related to having multiple targets, where it would fail on only 1 target.

To resolve it I had to ctrl-click the CoreTelephone.framework and select to add it to all my schemes.

The exact error I was getting was "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo","