# Is it possible to make a iPhone app using only c++?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Utilizing C++ in iOS and Mac OS X applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759573/utilizing-c-in-ios-and-mac-os-x-applications)

I want to make a app with only C++ (with out using Objective C).

If I get the `UIScrollView` kind of class,  then I can use that for Android.

Can any one guide me on this?

Comment: AFAIK Apple is pretty strict and only accepts ObjC (not even C), but I think you can get around it.

Comment: @Pubby - I am curious how they can discriminate between Objective-C and plain C which is fully contained in Objective-C.

Comment: Apple will allow C++ and C mixed with Objective-C. I've used a lot of plain C in my project for raw sockets and never had any problems with the Appstore approval.

Answer (score 5):

Well no, not really. Since there is no C++ version of `UIKit` you will need to do all the UI stuff in Objective-C. There are some bridges for Objective-C++.

You are allowed to mix C++/C with Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Well theoretically you can because all of the Objective-C runtime can be accessed using C functions like `objMsgSend()`.  However, why bother?  Just learn Objective-C (or possibly, more relevantly, Objective-C++).  There's nothing to stop you from coding most of the application in C++ and just doing the UI in Objective-C.

Who knows, you may come to like it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can do a little iPhone development in C++. There is Objective-C++, but I don't know if it's supported a lot.

But I don't think you should really use *only* C++. I propose coding the UI in Objective-C then writing the logic etc. in C++ if you want.

Comment: If i code the UI in objective-C, i con not get iPhone scrolling, ui affect in android or other.

Answer (score 0):

There are some frameworks (like [crossmob](http://crossmobs.com/) and [libnui](http://libnui.net/)) that allow you to write plain old-school C++ code without using Objective-C. But there is no way to use directly Apple SDK with C++, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your model on C++. But your controller and view you have to implement on Objective-C. Because UIKit it's 100% Objective-C Framework. I think you can write OpenGL Game in Xcode only with C++ if you want.