# Compiling C++ with SDL on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, compiler-errors, sdl

I thought Ubuntu and OS X would have similar interfaces for compiling a C/C++ program with SDL but nothing I am trying, or finding on Google seems to be working.

I have found a solution for Xcode, but I am not using Xcode. I am writing my programs from Sublime Text 2 and compiling via command-line since I prefer it and work much faster that way.

Long story short, I am receiving an array of errors with each attempt and thus far I have copied `SDL.framework` into my `/Library/Frameworks` directory.

**This is the closest I have gotten to actually compiling:**

```
[ 674 / 174 / 0 ] $ compcpsdl

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_main", referenced from:
      -[SDLMain applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in ccYYA0Ea.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Terminal command (i.e. compcpsdl)**

```
g++ -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers main.cpp SDLmain.m -framework SDL -framework Cocoa
```

**With the following project structure:**

```
Project-Directory/
--- main.cpp
--- SDLMain.m
--- SDLMain.h
```

**And lastly, the following source code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

It appears I'm doing everything correctly, yet nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: [Note sure if this is relevant?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8221508/1171191) It would match your linking error.

Comment: @BoBTFish many thanks. It didn't solve my question but one of the other answers satisfied a secondary query I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think SDL does sometimes a bit strange stuff with the main function it assumes the mainfunction is defined in one way. Notice that I added `int argc` and `char** argv` to the definition of you main function.

Try:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

I encountered this problem also once and it was quite mystifying.
for more info see this stackoverflow question: [Why SDL defines main macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976084/why-sdl-defines-main-macro)

Comment: Oh wow. It just compiled successfully then. It appears that SDLmain.m is required for Cocoa and not native C++ (which is what I want). Removing SDLmain.m and -framework Cocoa from the compile command results in another error, if I leave them in it compiles, however.

Comment: Ignore my above comment, I realise SDLmain.m etc... is required for the program to quote: "SDL application can be a well-behaving OS X application." Thanks @BoBTFish