# Segmentation fault when calling SDL_SetVideoMode

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm having problem pinning down what is wrong here.

I'm part of a group and we're using SDL for graphics. When I run our test_SDL.cc program (just to see everything is set up properly), I'm the only one getting a segmentation fault.

Here's the relevant code:

```
int main(int argc, char** arg)
 {
  // Initializing
  if(-1 == SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING))
        return 1;

  SDL_Surface* screen{nullptr};
  SDL_Surface* hello{nullptr};

  screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
  ...
}
```

When SDL_SetVideoMode(...) is executed I get the segmentation fault. Any clues to what it could be?

I'm running on Mac OS Mavericks, and compiling with terminal

```
Pingul % gcc-mp-4.8 -lstdc++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic `sdl-config --cflags --libs` test_SDL.cc
```

If it could make a difference all other in my group uses Ubuntu. Thankful for all help!

EDIT:
Crash rapport
    Process:         a.out [918]
    Path:            /Users/USER/Documents/*/a.out
    Identifier:      a.out
    Version:         0
    Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:  zsh [297]
    Responsible:     Terminal [155]
    User ID:         501

```
Date/Time:       2013-12-08 21:30:32.860 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  EF22B2C8-6B58-F80F-184F-61D6ECE0B474


Crashed Thread:  1

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib              0x000000010d59c3a9 -[SDL_QuartzWindow display] + 33
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9460a681 __67-[NSWindow     _updateSettingsSendingScreenChangeNotificationIfNeeded:]_block_invoke + 237
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9460a548 NSPerformWithScreenUpdatesDisabled + 65
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9460a4f7 -[NSWindow     _updateSettingsSendingScreenChangeNotificationIfNeeded:] + 197
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff946027e1 -[NSWindow _setFrame:updateBorderViewSize:] + 914
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff94601d5e -[NSWindow _oldPlaceWindow:] + 652
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9460118c -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:stashSize:] +     1633
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff946155bc -[NSWindow setFrameOrigin:] + 369
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9483d561 -[NSWindow center] + 278
9   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib              0x000000010d59a386 QZ_SetVideoMode + 1652
10  libSDL-1.2.0.dylib              0x000000010d5915a9 SDL_SetVideoMode + 906
11  a.out                           0x000000010d46c7d4 SDL_main + 203
12  a.out                           0x000000010d46c0bb -[SDLMain applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 49
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff935c7fcc     __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff934bbc5d _CFXNotificationPost + 2893
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9419d4aa -[NSNotificationCenter     postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944e7b79 -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 289
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944e78ac -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification]     + 195
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944e4796 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling)     _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 570
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944e41eb -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling)     _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 242
20  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff941bbeaa -[NSAppleEventManager     dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 294
21  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff941bbd1d _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 106
22  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8de11e1f aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*,     unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 381
23  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8de11c32 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*)     + 31
24  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8de11b36 aeProcessAppleEvent + 315
25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8e0a55f1 AEProcessAppleEvent + 56
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944e00f6 _DPSNextEvent + 1026
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944df8db -[NSApplication     nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944d39cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
29  a.out                           0x000000010d46c6df main + 1305
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff936a05fd start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a4c4e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93697f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9369afb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a4c5662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e52343d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e523152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a4c4e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93697f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9369afb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a4c4e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93697f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9369afb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a4c4e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93697f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9369afb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a4c4e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93697f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9369afb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000002000170  rbx: 0x000000010e081000  rcx: 0x000000010e080f28  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000004  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x000000010e080f50  rsp: 0x000000010e080f28
   r8: 0x00007fff922df8d7   r9: 0x0000000000000164  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000070001  r15: 0x0000000000001003
  rip: 0x00007fff8a4c4e6a  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x000000010f352000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000170
Trap Number:     133
```

And also

```
VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=155.7M resident=54.7M(35%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=101.0M(65%)
Writable regions: Total=71.8M written=2836K(4%) resident=3764K(5%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=68.1M(    95%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG image                              4K
CG shared images                    212K
Dispatch continuations             8192K
Kernel Alloc Once                     8K
MALLOC                             36.6M
MALLOC (admin)                       32K
Memory Tag 242                       12K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              10.6M
VM_ALLOCATE                        16.3M
__DATA                             19.3M
__IMAGE                             528K
__LINKEDIT                         66.1M
__TEXT                             89.6M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        28.2M
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             332.2M

Model: MacBookAir4,1, BootROM MBA41.0077.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.74f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xE9), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100    .22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS128C, 121,33 GB
USB Device: FaceTime Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 8.1
```

I hope that this is the relevant information. Please tell me if I'm formatting this weird as well.

Comment: what version of sdl are you/your group members using?

Comment: @itwasntpete We're using 1.2.15. After your suggestion I tried changing 32 to 24, and going through all of the options available. The only one working was SDL_FULLSCREEN, all other also caused a segmentation fault. Do you have insight of why? If not I'm going to work with what I've got, but would be fun otherwise as well :)

Comment: did you tried [SDL_GetVideoInfo()](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlvideoinfo.html) to see what's "possibly" best? also, please post a trace of the error.

Comment: Yes I went through the VideoInfo object, but what exactly am I looking for? I'll update the question with a crash rapport.

Comment: seen in the trace SDL_main is still called. did you somewhere undefined sdl main? `undef main` somewhere in the code? or try to make your main to SDL_main. like see [here](http://jonmacey.blogspot.ch/2012/09/getting-started-with-sdl-part-2-simple.html)

Comment: Tried adding the undef main as you suggested, and also followed the link you gave but nothing happened. Do you know if SDL does compile on Xcode 5? I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221151/settting-up-sdl-on-mac-os-x-lion-with-xcode-4 that seemed very similar, only difference he/she compiled with Xcode.

Comment: i don't know that, sorry. have you tried to compile his example? also try to compile with sdl 2. your sdl version seems to be 1.2.0 looking at the trace log `libSDL-1.2.0`.

Comment: Been trying for a while now but to no avail. It works on fullscreen though, so at least I can run the application :) I thank you for your help and time, awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the bits-per-pixel is not realy a good idea. Also not every Mac-OS supports 32 bit on SDL. Try some other value's. 0 is for autoassign, which is often not running on Mac. I think 24 should do it.

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 24, SDL_SWSURFACE);
```

You also could use `SDL_GetVideoInfo();` to determine which mode you should use.