# UIView animations in board game

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation

Hello I am trying to create snakes and ladder type board game. and I am moving player pieces with UIView animations.But it is moving player pieces with shortest path it found. I want to move player pieces horizontally , vertical and diagonally .I used below code

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                animations:^{
                                       playerOneImage.center = boardView.center;


                                       // Here you can disable the game play so that while animation is in progress, player cannot do other operations like rotating the dice, etc...
                                  }
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                       if(finished) {
                                           NSLog(@"Player moved to square:");

                                          // Here you can enable the game play that disabled when animation started...
                                      }
                                   } ];
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CAKeyframeAnimation` on the view's layer, instead of using `+[UIView animateWithDuration:...]`.

First, you may need to add the QuartzCore framework to your target.  If you don't know how to do that, read [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)  Also add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to your app's `.pch` header file.

Now you can animate the view along a path.  First, create a UIPath for the path you want the view to follow.  This example will move the view to the right 50 points, and then down 100 points:

```
CGPoint position = self.playerOneImage.layer.position;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:position];
position.x += 50; [path addLineToPoint:position];
position.y += 100; [path addLineToPoint:position];
```

Next, create a `CAKeyframeAnimation` that will animate the position property along that path:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.path = path.CGPath;
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
```

There are lots of options for changing the speed at which the layer moves along the path - check the docs.

Next, you have to set the layer's position to the *final position*, where you want it to be after the animation is over.  It seems weird, but it's absolutely necessary:

```
// Important: you must actually set the layer's position!
// Otherwise the animation will put it back at the start
// when the animation ends.  You should set the layer's
// final position, then add the animation.
self.playerOneImage.layer.position = position;
```

Finally, add the animation to the layer:

```
[self.playerOneImage.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

And you're done.

All together for easy cut/paste:

```
CGPoint position = self.playerOneImage.layer.position;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:position];
position.x += 50; [path addLineToPoint:position];
position.y += 100; [path addLineToPoint:position];
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.path = path.CGPath;
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
// Important: you must actually set the layer's position!
// Otherwise the animation will put it back at the start
// when the animation ends.  You should set the layer's
// final position, then add the animation.
self.playerOneImage.layer.position = position;
[self.playerOneImage.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```