# Getting "apple mach-o linker id error undefined symbols for architecture i386" when implement a Library in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, paypal

I'm having troubles to implement the PayPal Library in XCode 4.
I get this error when I try to build the project:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_xmlParseMemory", referenced from:
>         -[AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding_CancelPreapproval connectionDidFinishLoading:] in libPayPalMPL.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         -[AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding_ConfirmPreapproval connectionDidFinishLoading:] in libPayPalMPL.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         -[AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding_ConvertCurrency connectionDidFinishLoading:] in libPayPalMPL.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         -[AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding_ExecutePayment connectionDidFinishLoading:] in libPayPalMPL.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         -[AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding_GetPaymentOptions connectionDidFinishLoading:] in libPayPalMPL.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         -[AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding_PaymentDetails connectionDidFinishLoading:] in libPayPalMPL.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         -[AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11Binding_Pay connectionDidFinishLoading:] in libPayPalMPL.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
>         ...

Searching on the web I found that this is a tipical error when passing from XC3 to XC4. Maybe the Library isn't updated. But that file .a that you see there seems to be uneditable.

Comment: Have you checked whether the library is in `Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries`?

Comment: Is already in there, what else could be?

Comment: I solved it. Have to load 3 frameworks: libXML, Security and libz.

Comment: Make it an answer and accept it that others can profit from your experience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved. Have to load 3 frameworks: libXML, Security and libz.

Comment: Why didn't the PayPal team just say that we need those libraries? Shit!

Comment: **[How to load a framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really helped me out. 

PayPal MPL documentation is really lacking!