# What frameworks do I need for libPayPalMPL.a?

Tags: ios, paypal

This thread says I need three, but I have several options with those prefixes and don't know which three to link exactly.  I'm working with iOS 5.1, XCode 4.3.2

[Getting "apple mach-o linker id error undefined symbols for architecture i386" when implement a Library in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670162/getting-apple-mach-o-linker-id-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-w)

I've been having bad experiences with what seems to be deprecated documentation, tutorials with questions from the author of the in there, incomplete documentation, sample code that does not work...not cool paypal, not cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to load exactly these -

1. Security.framework
2. libxml2.dylib
3. libz.1.2.5.dylib

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, i just looked at the demo app and began adding each one.
libxml2.dylib
libz.dylib
Security.framework