# Why can't I access NSEvent?

Tags: objective-c, keyboard-events

I am trying to use NSEvent, however if I try to access the class I get an error. I at first thought that it was because I was trying to use it from the main method, but even when I tried to use it in a class it still won't build.

Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <appkit/NSEvent.h>

@interface Test : NSObject
@end

@implementation Test

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"New Test Class");
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSEvent class]);
    }
    return self;
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSUInteger eventMask = NSKeyDownMask;
        Test *t = [[Test alloc] init];
        /*id eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:eventMask handler:^(NSEvent *incomingEvent)
                           {
                               NSEvent *result = incomingEvent;

                               NSLog(@"%i", (int)[result keyCode]);

                               return result;
                           }];*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you linking against the AppKit framework?  Your `#import` statements would lead me to believe that step might have been missed.  You can fix it by adding AppKit to your project in Xcode, or if you use the command line, add `-framework AppKit`.

Comment: How do I add the framework or use the command line? Sorry I'm new to objective-c.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4