# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 error when building for simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o   "_kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters", referenced from:
>         -[RootViewController locationManager] in RootViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 collect2: ld returned 1
>   exit status

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must link your binary to CoreLocation.framework. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you linked your binary to [CoreLocation.Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123)? [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1) is how you link frameworks to your binary.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4) question will also help you to link framework with your project