# SQLite3 getting errors in xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode, sqlite

My Application was working perfectly on Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.2.  Built with no errors and ran with the SQL database with no problem.  I upgraded to Lion and Xcode 4.3.2 and when I Build, I get errors of "/usr/include/sqlite3.h file not found" on my #import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h" lines of code.  Any one else have this problem or have any suggestions?  I have tried deleting the libsqlite3.dylib from the Project Navigator, and then adding it back via the + sign in the Build Phases tab in the Link Binary With Libraries, but the error persists.

Answer (score 6):

When updating from `Snow Leopard` to `Lion` and `Xcode 4.2` to `Xcode 4.5`, your will got error: " '/usr/include/sqlite3.h' file not found".

Solution:

- Add library: `"libsqlite3.0.dylib"` in the `Target > Build Phases`
- Change `#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"` to `#import "sqlite.h"` in
  your code

---

**Update to author's post:** It is not `#import "sqlite.h"`. It is: `#import <sqlite3.h>`

---

Answer (score 1):

I think what your problem is you need to include the SQLite 3.0 Framework into your project.

Refer to this question if you don't know how to add a framework:
[How to “add existing frameworks” in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

The framework you want is libsqlite3.0.dylib

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried including the libsqlite3.0.dylib in my framework, and changed my import statement to #import "/usr/include/sqlite3.0.h", but I still get the same error '/usr/include/sqlite3.0h' file not found.  I tried removing the other sqlite3.dylib framework, but same error.  I don't know if this has any bearing on it, but when I upgraded to xcode 4.3.2, I left the old xcode 4.2 on the system.

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT.  I kept playing around with the code, and I found that in either Lion or Xcode 4.3.2 (not sure which one is causing it), I only have to have the import statement say #import "sqlite3.h", not the whole path of "/usr/include/sqlite3.h".  I fixed all my import statements and it works perfectly now.  I think this question can be closed, unless there are any other comments.

Comment: Glad you figured everything out.

Comment: @Bill 's comment should be added to the answer (ugh, and this answer should be selected, too.)