# How to solve the errror ""_CGAffineTransformMakeRotation", referenced from:"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When i use the following code i am getting the error message that says

> ""_CGAffineTransformMakeRotation", referenced from:"

```
    companyNameLbl.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(30);
```

Can anyone please tell me what will be the reason for this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, those transformations require that you link against the CoreGraphics Framework.

See [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4) if you have difficulties adding new frameworks in XCode.

Comment: a.k.a. QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

Comment: @Sean: No, link against, not include. If he's already using the function, he's presumably already included the framework header.

Comment: @Sean It is more about the linking that the inclusion of the header file, otherwise he would have got a compilation error, not this type or linking error.

Comment: Add the CoreGraphics framework, I just tested it on my side. Without this framework I get the exact same linking error that you have.