# Unable to link ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios5, alassetslibrary

I am struggling with linking ALAssetsLibrary in my code.

I have googled a lot on this and followed more than one tutorial to the last dot yet I am still where I began.

```
Ld /Users/vedprakash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PickThumb-gmvprlkgmgexedeojbaoeidbadnw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PickThumb.app/PickThumb normal i386
    cd "/Users/vedprakash/Documents/XCode Projects/PickThumb"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/vedprakash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PickThumb-gmvprlkgmgexedeojbaoeidbadnw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/vedprakash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PickThumb-gmvprlkgmgexedeojbaoeidbadnw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/vedprakash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PickThumb-gmvprlkgmgexedeojbaoeidbadnw/Build/Intermediates/PickThumb.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PickThumb.build/Objects-normal/i386/PickThumb.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/vedprakash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PickThumb-gmvprlkgmgexedeojbaoeidbadnw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PickThumb.app/PickThumb

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PickThumbViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to add the `AssetsLibrary` framework to the “Link Binary With Libraries” build phase of your `PickThumb` target.

[How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Comment: After adding I am receiving this error:

    `ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/vedprakash/Documents/XCode Projects/PickThumb/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)`

Comment: That is not the correct location for the `AssetsLibrary` framework.  I don't think you followed the directions in the link.

Comment: I have added the framework as it is in the link and the library shows up in the list under "Link Binary with Libraries"

Comment: The link command should say `-framework AssetsLibrary` if you added it correctly.  It should not have a path that ends with `/AssetsLibrary`.

Comment: Thanks Rob :). I removed and added the library and it build successfully.

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 10.2 I just added

```
AssetsLibrary.framework
```

in the Target>Build Phases> Link Binary With Libraries section