# Calling an external class in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, linker-errors

I have this class for button which was added to my project workspace. I had

```
    linker error ( Apple Mach-o Linker Error)
```

Then again i opened a new project  and added this class.
In my ViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
    #import <UIView+Glow.h>  

    @interface ViewController:UIViewController
    @property(non atomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *testView;
    end
```

And in my ViewController.m

Added is the screenshot

```
    #importViewController.h
    -(void) viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [testView startGlowing]
    }
```

I had

```
     *unrecognized selector sent to instance error
```

This is the class 
I suggest you use the [Glow Category of UIView made by secret lab](https://github.com/thesecretlab/UIView-Glow).

Any suggestion on how to call this class?

attached are the screenshots of the issue
[image: the UIView+Glow implementation file]

[image: imported into my view controller implementation file]
[image: error information]

Comment: Just a tip: I don't know if this is a typo or not, but in your property declaration, the property attribute "non atomic" is supposed to be spelled "nonatomic". You likely would've gotten an Xcode build failure for that type of error, so I'm guessing it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have copied `UIView+Glow.h` into your project, you should use this to import it:

```
#import "UIView+Glow.h"
```

You should not use the angle brackets (`<UIView+Glow.h>`) to import headers that are part of your project.

If you have not copied `UIView+Glow.m` into your project, you need to do so.

If you have copied `UIView+Glow.m` into your project, you need to make sure it is included in the “Compile Sources” build phase of your target.

The easiest way to check is to open `UIView+Glow.m` in the primary editor.  Then choose the View > Utilities > Show File Inspector menu item.  Look at the File Inspector (on the right side of the Xcode window).  Make sure it's showing information for `UIView+Game.m`.  Then look at the “Target Membership” section.  Make sure the checkbox next to your target is checked.

#### Update

The three linker errors in your final screenshot happened because you haven't added the `QuartzCore` framework to your project.  This is the framework that contains the Core Animation classes.

If you don't know how to add a framework to your project, look at [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use the following line at the top of the implementation file where you want to use the glow methods:

```
#import "UIView+Glow.h"
```