# getting error message when trying to use QuartzCore animation

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-core

I have a replay level button. When the user presses this replay level button i reset all my games properties so as to reset the level. But, this is not enough. I also want to make the level look like it is completely new, so I want to add animation to the view controller exactly like the cross dissolve animation of the modal segue. So to do this, I added this code into my replayLevel method.

```
-(IBAction)replayLevel:(id)sender
{
//reset my levels properties
[self resetGameProperties];

//add the cool modal cross dissolve animation

CATransition *transition =[CATransition animation];
transition.duration=.5;
transition.type=kCATransitionFade;
transition.delegate=self;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
self.view.hidden=YES;
self.view.hidden=NO;

}
```

I also in my interface file remembered to add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and everything seemed to be fine, except when i build and run I get this error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_kCATransitionFade", referenced from:
      -[ViewController replayButton:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If my code to duplicate a modal cross dissolve segue is bad, i would be happy to accept any different opinions as to how i should go about doing that, but otherwise, could anyone please help me get this error  away?

Any help is very Helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `QuartzCore` framework to your target.

[How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)