# Add CoreTelephony Framework in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've never worked in Xcode before since I just make my games in unity; however, one of the ad plugins I'm using wants me to perform the step below. How exactly do I add that framework in xcode(Also do I need to download the framework online or is it already included)?

*— Step 4: Add CoreTelephony to your iOS project (iOS only)

Add the `CoreTelephony` framework to the Xcode project that Unity generates.*

Comment: A google search would've taken you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4

Comment: ha thanks. I was being to specific with my google searches and couldn't find anything :D

Answer (score 3):

I've written a post on how to add frameworks to an Xcode project:

http://cupsofcocoa.com/2012/06/16/adding-frameworks-to-an-xcode-project/

Basically:

1. Select the top-level project
2. Go to Build Phases, expand Link Binaries with Library
3. Click the +, select the framework you want, and click Add

Comment: This is the equivalent link, although of course this content is probably outdated at this point: https://cupsofcocoa.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/adding-frameworks-to-an-xcode-project/