# how to add a library to xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks

this has been asked plenty of times, but I always find them hard to follow. Its quite simple.
How do you add a library and/or framework to xcode and/ or your xcode project. I need all the steps between downloading the library, to typing the #include  in the code. But I also need some context behind each step, other wise it won't stick in my mind and I'll back here in a week. Bear in mind I have an limited understanding of the xcode development environment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a real question and must be opened.

Comment: Also see [How to “add existing frameworks” in Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4). 1100+ upvotes means its a pretty good question with pretty good answers.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the screenshots and you are good to go

[image]

[image]

[image]