# Xcode standard C++ library binaries path

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, static-libraries

Where does Xcode's linker look up the standard C++ library binary files? Can I add additional libraries to this location and have them linked automatically so as no to have to add them manually to every project?

EDIT: I don't want to add libs like `boost` manually to every project, I want them in the path by default. Is this possible?

Comment: It looks up what's configured with your toolchain.

Comment: . /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeD‌​efault.xctoolchain/u‌​sr/include

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add a library to xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191039/how-to-add-a-library-to-xcode)