# I am getting the following errors - Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error

Tags: ios

I am getting the following errors but no errors showing in either the .h or .m files

> Apple Mach-O Linker (`id`) Error  "`_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID`", referenced from -`[firstViewController playSound:]`  in `FirstViewController.o`

Both the .h and implementation file is clean and does not show any errors on the pages.

Comment: Have you added all the frameworks to you project? (in your case probably AudioToolbox)

Comment: Have you added `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `AudioToolbox.framework` to your project.

Instructions on doing this are here: [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)