# link to a book in iBook store from an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, itunes

After looking around I could not get a straight answer to the following case: can I link to a book in the iBook store from my iphone app without integrating the in-app purchases API?

As far as I know, iBooks does charge you for placing the book, so my logic says that it should be possible since otherwise you would be charged twice.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you just trying to display a view so the user can buy the book from iBooks from within your app?

Comment: I would like to have a button in my app that says "buy our book on iBooks" which will redirect to our book on the iBook app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your app is targeting iOS 6.0 you can use the new `SKStoreProductViewController` to allow users to purchase iTunes, App Store, and iBooks content directly from your app without having to leave it.

Here is how to present it from a `UIViewController`. You must [add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377682/1378694) the StoreKit.framework to your application.

`ViewController.h`

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface UIViewController : UIViewController <SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

`ViewController.m`

```
-(void)showProductPageForProductID:(NSInteger)productID {

    SKStoreProductViewController *sv = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    sv.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *product = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: @(productID)};
    [sv loadProductWithParameters:product completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {

            if(result)
                [self presentModalViewController:sv animated:YES];
            else {
               //product not found, handle appropriately
            }
        }];

}    
-(void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController {
            [viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

If your targeting devices below iOS 6.0 you can just use this:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-casual-vacancy/id518781282?mt=11"]];
```

Just replace that URL string with your link, and it will leave your app and enter the iBooks app displaying that product.

If you want to target both iOS 6.0 and lower, you can just check if they have the new `SKStoreProductViewController` by using the following conditional

```
 if([SKStoreProductViewController class]) {
     //show the SKStoreProductViewController
}
else {
     //use UIApplication's openURL:
}
```

---

In order to get the Apple product ID for a product, you can just check the URL to the product for example:

`http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-casual-vacancy/id518781282?mt=11`

The product ID is `518781282`. It comes after the `id` portion in the URL. Don't include the `?` or anything after it.

Comment: Will I need to set up the IAP API? OR am I good to go just like that? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It's not an "In App Purchase", so the above code is all you need.

Comment: One last question...what is ProductID? Where do I get it from?

Comment: It works good, but when test on my device it dose not install apps, anyone know why?